# Calling jQuery document.ready handler with apply method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function, document-ready

Below is the code I am using in a project with some complex dependencies. After I have made sure that all the dependencies have been loaded I fire the **onReadyCallback()** also given below. I have two questions :

1. Is it correct to use, anonymousHandler.apply(MyNameSpace), the apply method on an anonymous Handler being called for Document.ready
2. From what I understand, because I am using the apply method the anonymous function will fire immediately irregardless of document's ready state. Then how can I pass in the context of **MyNameSpace** to the **anonymousHandler** so that "this" inside the function refers to MyNameSpace

   ```
   var onReadyCallback = function(){
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          if(!this.loggedIn()){
             return;
          }
          ...Lots of Code referring to MyNameSpace using "this"

       }.apply(MyNameSpace));
   };

   //load the additional files that are needed and fire onReadyCallback
   MyNameSpace.Util.loadFiles(defaultJsFiles,function(){ 
       MyNameSpace.Util.require(['My.App','My.Theme','My.DomHandler'], function(){
          onReadyCallback.apply(window);          
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: I hope the rest of your code doesn't look like this. No offense...

Comment: @yanick-rochon :) why you think its too messy? Any tips (a blog post, book or two) would be much appreciated...

Comment: since the answer to this comment needs some development, I am adding an answer to your question

Comment: @yanick-rochon, sure. Thanks any suggestions to help improve my programming style are always very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this, using an anonymous function and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call)?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        // this == MyNamespace
    }).call(MyNamespace);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, using another anonymous function does seem to solve the problem of passing context.

I am still quite new to javascript: I take it that my assumption that anonymousHandler.apply(MyNameSpace) will fire immediately irregardless of document's ready state is correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be run whenever that callback is run.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the `ready` event jQuery function is called like this

```
$(function() { /* ... */ });
// or 
jQuery(function() { /* ... */ });
// or
jQuery(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Bottom line, the function is not given a particular context; the actual context given by jQuery to the function is the `HTMLDocument` element, regardless of the argument (in the last example, `document`). Why is this so is another subject.

Generally, each of these functions are called later, after everything has been loaded, but not necessarily. In your case, there is a reference to `MyNameSpace` before the `ready` event happens. Even if Javascript is a [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser)-type language, and it will find the symbol declared later, this is not a good practice. What if `MyNameSpace` would be set to something else later on, before jQuery triggers the `ready` callback functions? Your `ready` callback would not get that new reference. Unless intentional, the reference should be made *inside* the `ready` callback, when everything is.... ready.

Then, inside the `ready` callback, there are other techniques to assign a context to a function. [lonesomeday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday) have pretty much given the correct way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
(function() {
    // this == MyNamespace
}).call(MyNamespace);
```

The above code executes an anonymous function right away, where `this == MyNameSpace`

**note** : the difference between *apply* and *call* is decribed [here](http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=JavaScript_call_and_apply)

Now, comes the bottom part of the code you provided :

```
//load the additional files that are needed and fire onReadyCallback
MyNameSpace.Util.loadFiles(defaultJsFiles,function(){ 
    MyNameSpace.Util.require(['My.App','My.Theme','My.DomHandler'], function(){
       onReadyCallback.apply(window);          
    });
});
```

This is problematic, and unnecessary. Is the function `onReadyCallback` only needed there, or will it be called several times? If it needs to be called only once, spare the global namespace, and simply do :

```
//load the additional files that are needed and fire onReadyCallback
MyNameSpace.Util.loadFiles(defaultJsFiles,function(){ 
    MyNameSpace.Util.require(['My.App','My.Theme','My.DomHandler'], function(){

       // if everything is done loading, the function will be executed, otherwise
       // it's execution will be postponed later
       jQuery(function() {

           // create our nicely wrapped anonymous function now
           (function() {
              if(!this.loggedIn()){
                 return;
              }
              // ...Lots of Code referring to MyNameSpace using "this"

           })(MyNameSpace);  // grab our most recent reference of `MyNameSpace`

       });
    });
});
```

If you don't like the indentation (it's merely a developer's taste), replace everything in the `ready` callback with (something like) :

```
 initMyNameSpace.apply(MyNameSpace);
```

and create your function outside, on the global space :

```
 function initMyNameSpace() {
    if(!this.loggedIn()){
       return;
    }
    // ...Lots of Code referring to MyNameSpace using "this"

 };
```

But I would recommand, at least, to put it in the `require` callback function so it...

1. ...does not pollute the global namespace with a run-once function
2. ...is not accessible from anywhere (keep it private)
3. ...can be found quickly when editing the source code
4. etc.

**note** : usually, *apply* and *call* are used to avoid repeatedly accessing objects like `some.thing.pretty.deep = value;` or when one function needs to be applied to many but not all objects, and thus extending the object's prototype is just not a good idea.

This is my opinion anyway, and how I would do things, without any more knowledge of your code or what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write a detailed explanation, has some very useful points/tips... will certainly help deepen my understanding of this stuff.